# iPhone backlight blinks on then goes out. What are my options?

Tags: iphone

This morning I woke up to find my iPhone dark. If I pressed the home button to turn on the screen, the backlight would flash on briefly and then die. I've turned it on and off, done a hard reboot (home+lock), and I'm in the process of trying a restore.

Has anyone ever seen a similar issue?

The phone was purchased last June with a contract from ATT from an Apple store. If I take the phone in, will they fix it or replace it?

What should I do next?

Answer (score 3):

You should take your phone in. They will fix it if they can and it's cheaper for them than giving you a new.

If you try to fix it yourself they can put the blame on you, so don't touch the hardware.

Comment: +1 It certainly wouldn't hurt to ask. If they say no you've nothing but a trip to the shop.

Answer (score 1):

It may be your proximity sensor. It's what causes the backlight to turn off when you put the phone to your face and turn back on when you move away. I was told that that's one of the few things Apple Care does actually cover.

But before you take it in, do you have a bumper on your iPhone? If so, it may be covering the sensor, which, while facing the phone, is just to the left of the earpiece. If your bumper (or maybe a dirty screen protector) is covering it, that may cause the screen to stay dark.

Hope this helps!